# Which iOS devices support local speech to text and is it possible to force that behaviour?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, speech-to-text

There is information that suggests some of the more modern iOS devices no longer need to contact Apples servers in order to perform speech to text.  I cannot find information about which devices can handle the workload, and how to force the app to run that locally.

Here is a site that shows offline dictation in regards to a iPhone keyboard: https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/quick-tip-offline-dictation-with-iphone-6s-and-iphone-6s-plus

Here is a tutorial that suggests apple is entirely in control of the location where the audio is transformed into text: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-speech-recognition-api-in-ios-10--cms-28032

Comment: Can you provide reference for said information?

Comment: Thanks Losiowaty, I added some more information to the query.  Are you working on something similar?